# Root directory in CSS in a ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I have an using ASP.NET MVC 4.5 that uses some css files.
The css refers to some images.

The css file Is located in this path:

```
WebSiteRoot\Content\css\services\File.CSS
```

The image is located in this path:

```
\WebSiteRoot\Content\img\servicesbubble\image.png
```

The css has this calling:

```
background:transparent url('../../img/servicesbubble/image.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
```

When I run the app in the localhost it works. But when I upload to the hosting (Appharbor) It doesn't work.
Why? What is the best way to reffer to the root of an app?

In the server the http get is tried to this wrong URL

```
WebSite.com/img/servicesbubble/desktop.png
```

**Update:** I am using the .NET framework 4.5 feature called bundling for merge these CSS with another CSS.

Comment: Could you share URL of your AppHarbor hosted site so that we can have a look?

Comment: file references from a css file shouldn't be a problem if the paths don't change between environments.

Comment: Of course @Michal this it the url http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/Services Check the wrong callings to http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/img/servicesbubble/desktop.png and
http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/img/servicesbubble/uc.png

Comment: Try `url('/content/img/servicesbubble/image.png')` in the `css`. The opening / denotes the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually coming from the fact you're minifying the css to a different directory than the CSS originally existed in.

More specifically: **http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/Content/css/servicescss**?v=sdm08D5sRu2I00dA0phyVTYZ_QU8Nfp27wHtmmE0Gzk1

So ../../  puts you at http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/Content

Urls in CSS files are always relative to location of the CSS file itself.

Comment: I dont think so. The minification and bundling in MVC 4.5 allows this.

Comment: Does bundling rewrite the paths in the minified CSS? (clarification)

Answer (score 2):

Your paths to the CSS files seems to change.  The two CSS files I see related to your website   are http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/Content/css/servicescss?v=sdm08D5sRu2I00dA0phyVTYZ_QU8Nfp27wHtmmE0Gzk1 and http://tulpepwebsite.apphb.com/Content/GeneralCSS?v=9kvtUcooQua0D4nQT8wZ-4_Gm6OcRd-J5SkjMxwKiyQ1.  (The other is from the google fonts service.)  You need to figure out why that's happening.

Edit: Ok, I'm going to guess something.  You're probably using the [new ASP.NET 4.5 bundling feature](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification). But it doesn't make sense to bundle CSS flies in different directories, if you're doing that.

Comment: I am using the bundling feature of ASP.NET 4.5, and I am not bundling css in differente directories. I have sense in term of compress and simply your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS location is different than you think:

```
WebSiteRoot\Content\css\File.CSS
```

instead of

```
WebSiteRoot\Content\css\services\File.CSS
```